# get current session in mvc3 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

i define `session["username]"` in `Login.cs` when user want to login

```
    public static void SetLogin(string username, bool remmember)
        {
             HttpContext.Current.Session["username"] = username;
        }
```

and i want use value of `session["username"]` in UserPanelController

```
    public class UserPanelController : Controller
    {
        Customer cu;
        Customer.customer cust;
        public UserPanelController()
        {
            if (Login.ChekLogin())
            {
                cust = cu.Read(int.Parse(Session["username"].ToString()));
                // error Occur here Session is null
            }

        }
    }
```

i can't access to session because is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be attempting to use the Session in the constructor of an ASP.NET MVC controller. It's normal that it is null. The session is initialized at a later stage - in the [`Initialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.initialize%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method:

```
public class UserPanelController : Controller
{
    Customer cu;
    Customer.customer cust;

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        if (Login.ChekLogin())
        {
            cust = cu.Read(int.Parse(Session["username"].ToString()));
            // error Occur here Session is null
        }
    }
}
```

Also you seem to be attempting to cast the username to an integer. Are you sure that this is the case?

Also why are you using a Session for something that's already handled for you by the FormsAuthentication?